# Implementing 4-dimensional Halton Sequence

Tags: c++

The psuedocode for the Halton sequnce can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence). I wrote a function that does this but for some reason checking the Matlab results for the 4th dimensional Halton sequence my numbers do not match up and I am not sure why. Here is my code:

```
double Halton_Seq(int index, double base){
    double f = 1, r;
    while(index > 0){
        f = f/base;
        r = r + f*(fmod(index,base));
        index = index/base;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Here are the first 10 results I get:

```
1
0.25
0.5
0.75
0.0625
0.3125
0.5625
0.8125
0.125
0.375
```

Here is the first 10 results MATLAB gets:

```
  Columns 1 through 2

         0    0.5000

  Columns 3 through 4

    0.2500    0.7500

  Columns 5 through 6

    0.1250    0.6250

  Columns 7 through 8

    0.3750    0.8750

  Columns 9 through 10

    0.0625    0.5625
```

Comment: Your C++ code is fine aside from not initializing r. Your Matlab code is generating the sequence for base 2 not 4

Comment: @samgak Are you sure, I set d = 4 so I believe it is base 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `r` in line 2.

`r = 0;`

```
double Halton_Seq(int index, int base){
  double f = 1, r = 0;
  while(index > 0){
    f = f/base;
    r = r + f* (index% base);
    index = index/base;
  }
  return r;
}
// Output for 10 (base 2)
0.000000
0.500000
0.250000
0.750000
0.125000
0.625000
0.375000
0.875000
0.062500
0.562500
```

Comment: Does this produce the 4-dimensional Halton Sequence?